# Which exactly part of parsing should be done by the lexical analyser?

Tags: parsing, lexical-analysis

Does there exist a formal definition of the purpose, or at a clear best practice of usage, of lexical analysis (lexer) during/before parsing?

I know that the purpose of a lexer is to transform a stream of characters to a stream of tokens, but can't it happen that in some (context-free) languages the intended notion of a "token" could nonetheless depend on the context and "tokens" could be hard to identify without complete parsing?

There seems to be nothing obviously wrong with having a lexer that transforms every input character into a token and lets the parser do the rest.  But would it be acceptable to have a lexer that differentiates, for example, between a "unary minus" and a usual binary minus, instead of leaving this to the parser?

Are there any precise rules to follow when deciding what shall be done by the lexer and what shall be left to the parser?

Comment: How about this rule: "a lexer must work in linear time and logarithmic space"?

Comment: Another possible rule: "a lexer eliminates source code formatting"...

Answer (score 1):

> Does there exist a formal definition of the purpose [of a lexical analyzer]?

No. Lexical analyzers are part of the world of practical programming, for which formal models are useful but not definitive. A program which purports to do something should do that thing, of course, but "lexically analyze my programming language" is not a sufficiently precise requirements statement.

> … or a clear best practice of usage

As above, the lexical analyzer should do what it purports to do. It should also not attempt to do anything else. Code duplication should be avoided. Ideally, the code should be verifiable.

These best practices motivate the use of a mature and well-document scanner framework whose input language doubles as a description of the lexical grammar being analyzed. However, practical considerations based on the idiosyncracies of particular programming languages normally result in deviations from this ideal.

> There seems to be nothing obviously wrong with having a lexer that transforms every input character into a token…

In that case, the lexical analyzer would be redundant; the parser could simply use the input stream as is. This is called "scannerless parsing", and it has its advocates. I'm not one of them, so I won't enter into a discussion of pros and cons. If you're interested, you could start with the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scannerless_parsing) and follow its links. If this style fits your problem domain, go for it.

> can't it happen that in some (context-free) languages the intended notion of a "token" could nonetheless depend on the context?

Sure. A classic example is found in EcmaScript regular expression "literals", which need to be lexically analyzed with a completely different scanner. EcmaScript 6 also defines string template literals, which require a separate scanning environment. This could motivate scannerless processing, but it can also be implemented with an LR(1) parser with lexical feedback, in which the reduce action of particular marker non-terminals causes a switch to a different scanner.

> But would it be acceptable to have a lexer that differentiates, for example, between a "unary minus" and a usual binary minus, instead of leaving this to the parser?

Anything is acceptable if it works, but that particular example strikes me as not particular useful. LR (and even LL) expression parsers do not require any aid from the lexical scanner to show the context of a minus sign. (Naïve operator precedence grammars do require such assistance, but a more carefully thought out op-prec architecture wouldn't. However, the existence of LALR parser generators more or less obviates the need for op-prec parsers.)

Generally speaking, for the lexer to be able to identify *syntactic* context, it needs to duplicate the analysis being done by the parser, thus violating one of the basic best practices of code development ("don't duplicate functionality"). Nonetheless, it can occasionally be useful, so I wouldn't go so far as to advocate an absolute ban. For example, many parsers for yacc/bison-like production rules compensate for the fact that a naïve grammar is LALR(2) by specially marking ID tokens which are immediately followed by a colon.

Another example, again drawn from EcmaScript, is efficient handling of automatic semicolon insertion (ASI), which can be done using a lookup table whose keys are 2-tuples of consecutive tokens. Similarly, Python's whitespace-aware syntax is conveniently handled by assistance from the lexical scanner, which must be able to understand when indentation is relevant (not inside parentheses or braces, for example).

Comment: "that particular example strikes me as not particular useful" (about the "unary minus") -- IMO there is no such thing as "unary minus", for me `- 5` is a shorthand notation for `0 - 5`, but many consider that there is the "unary minus" which is different from the usual binary minus, and it is not uncommon to see in students' work expressions like `1 - -2`.  If we admit that there are two different operators with different arities denoted for some reason by the same symbol, IMO they are different tokens, if "tokens" wish to be something meaningful.

Comment: Could you give me some reference, please, for the <s>best</s> common tokenisation practices, like what kinds or categories of tokens are used commonly? For example, i've encountered this use of `id` tokens, but haven't figured out yet what they are.

Comment: `...if "tokens" wish to be something meaningful`: there is no need for a token to have a unique meaning. It is only necessary that the sequence of input characters making up the token needs to be distinguished from other character sequences. Best practice is almost always to leave it to the parser to assign semantics to a token. As an example, consider the C statement `a: a.a = 42;`. The first `a` is a label; the second is a variable name; the third is the name of a member of an aggregate type. The lexer could care less. All are identifiers.

Comment: @alexey: the tokens produced by the lexer should exactly correspond to the categories needed by the parser. They should not unnecessarily overclassify, and they should as precisely as possible distinguish between character sequences which need to be distinguished. They should not include character sequences which do not participate in the parse (comments, for example, unless the tools being build needs to parse comments, as in the automatic generation of documentation). That will vary from project to project...

Comment: `id` is commonly used for tokens which are identifiers of some form. In many simple languages, that would correspond to a sequence of letters, letter-like characters (such as `_` and maybe others, depending on the language) and digits, which starts with a letter (and possibly a letter-like character, again depending on the language). But that's far from universal. Some languages, for example, distinguish grammatically between identifiers starting with a capital letter and identifiers starting with a lower-case letter.

Comment: Within those guidelines, there is quite a lot of latitude. Should floating-point constants and integer constants be different token types? Normally, I would say "no", but there are times which it is useful to distinguish them in the grammar (such as languages whose syntax demands an integer constant in certain constructs). Also, some people like to use different token types to avoid having to pass a discriminated union from the scanner to the parser, but that will depend both on the purpose of the parse and the language in which the scanner and parser are written. Etc.